# Spectral Radius of a non negative matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-analysis

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a non-negative square matrix and $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a positive eigenvector. Prove that
\begin{gather*}
    \rho(A)=\max\limits_{x>0}\; \min\limits_{i=1,2,\dots,n}\frac{1}{x_i}\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}x_j=\min\limits_{x>0}\; \max\limits_{i=1,2,\dots,n}\frac{1}{x_i}\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}x_j.
\end{gather*}
using the inequality
\begin{gather*}
    \min\limits_{i=1,2,\dots,n}\left\{\frac{1}{x_i}\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}x_j\right\}\le \rho(A) \le  \max\limits_{i=1,2,\dots,n}\left\{\frac{1}{x_i}\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}x_j\right\}
\end{gather*}
I know that I need to use the fact that $x$ is a positive eigenvector, hence its corresponding eigenvalue is $\rho(A)$, I just can't grasp why the max and the min are used on the equality that needs to be proven.

Comment: Your statement *"I just can't grasp why the max and the min are used on the equality that needs to be proven"* is confusing. Since the question asks you to **use** the inequality, it would seem that you don't need to **prove** it. Are you talking about the max and min in the **equation** that you're trying to prove? Also, it's not clear from your post whether you actually need help answering the question.

Comment: I understand the question as follows: by taking $\max$ of the left hand side  in the second  inequality we get $\max_{x>0}\ldots \le \rho(A).$ Simiarly by taking min of the right hand side we get $\rho(A)\le \min_{x>0}\ldots  $ The task is to show that we have equality.